# How do i share a variable between threads using a "move" closure?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm trying to update the value of `a.n` inside a thread.  Said value is then used in the main thread for other purposes.

```rust
use std::thread;
struct foo{
    n: u32
}
fn main() {
    let mut a = foo{n: 0};
    thread::spawn( move || {
        loop {
            // change the value of a according to some conditions
            a.n = 1;
        }
    });
    assert_ne!(a.n,0);
}
```

The issue is that, in the code above, `a.n` remains 0 in the main thread.

Comment: You will find the answers to your question in [chapter 16 of the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-00-concurrency.html).

Comment: You may also want to read [chapter 4](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html) and [Disjoint Capture in Closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2021/disjoint-capture-in-closures.html) to understand why your code currently behaves the way it does. The tldr is the thread captures a copy of `a.n`, then sets that copy to 1, thereby not affecting the original in any way. Under edition 2018 it would capture `a` itself by value, and the code would not compile at all because the `assert_ne` would be trying to use a moved value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proximal issue that you observe comes from the closure capturing `a.n` (and copying it, since it's `Copy`). You can fix it by adding something like `let _ = &mut a` into the closure. But it still won't compile because your code has two other issues:

1. You attempt to modify a value from onee thread and read it from another. That's a data race, and safe Rust won't allow that to compile. It will prevent you from doing that by allowing only one `&mut` reference to exist at once, which your code violates.
2. Borrow checker will complain that the borrow doesn't live long enough in the closure you're sending to `thread::spawn()`. You need to either place shared data behind `Arc`, or use scoped threads.

A version of your code that fixes all three issues could look like this:

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::Mutex;

struct Foo {
    n: Mutex<u32>,
}

fn main() {
    let a = Foo { n: Mutex::new(0) };
    thread::scope(|scope| {
        let a = &a;
        scope.spawn(move || {
            loop {
                *a.n.lock().unwrap() = 1;
            }
        });
        // this assert runs in parallel with the thread, and will fail
        // if it executes before the first assignment.
        assert_ne!(*a.n.lock().unwrap(), 0);
    });
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5b4da20e1625982c3944d3df1ac4878d)